# Any online server with kerberos authentication with test accounts

Tags: httpclient, kerberos

Is there any server/proxy server available online supporting kerberos authentication and has some test accounts.

I want to test httpclient code but dont want to setup a Kerberos server locally. If any server is available online which has test account then it will be of great help.

Thanks,

-Vinay

Comment: A little too late, but I am currently looking for a similar solution. Did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be. You will need to have full control over the DNS from your provider and have 1:1 domain names to IPs.